# Is it possible to create a Listview with a Static text and a horizontal scroll in android?

Tags: android, listview

[image]

Here First Text will be stationary. For remaining items i need the horizontal scroll and when scrolling entire list rows should be scrolled left or right. can we do this by simple listviews in android?

Comment: You can use Recyclerview or TwoWayView@Anand Asir.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the LinearLayouts with ListsViews. The idea is to put the second ListView inside HorizontalScrollView.

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.idokov.layouttests.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="What is Lorem Ipsum?" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." />
                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The same thing i tried. But its scrolling only individual rows. I need to scroll the entire right portion.. from first row to last row with normal up and down listview scroll..